# AVPlayer Picture in Picture tvos

Tags: avplayer, tvos, avplayerviewcontroller

Does anyone know how to remove the smaller picture that appears when you pause a `AVPlayerViewController`?

[image]

Comment: Doesn't look possible, [AVPlayerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller). They even mention not to subclass it. This might be as close as you can get, [showsPlaybackControls](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller/1615824-showsplaybackcontrols)

Comment: pretty sure it is possible, checkout youtube. When the scrubber shows up, the thumbnail doesn't

Comment: They're probably using tvml to build their applications.